# How to Install Composer Require doctrine/dbal

Tags: php, laravel, doctrine, migration

In the Laravel framework, I am trying to modify my columns using  `change()` by migrations. Right now, I need to install...

```
composer require doctrine/dbal
```

I am not really sure how to install it, do I need to run a cmd command? I am using Laravel 5.4.

Comment: You do not. when you `require` it, it is automagically added to the `vendors` directory. Now, you need to run `composer dumpautoload` to have the newly required dependency autoloaded.

Comment: @Indah Ramona yes you need to install it via cmd

Comment: @Indah Ramona run `composer require doctrine/dbal` from your project root